# Update JSON local file from online JSON file

Tags: ios, json, updates

I want to update my local JSON file in the app when there is a new version of the file. I have the algorithm that checks if there is a new version or not.

But now, I need some code to change/update the local JSON for the online JSON.

Comment: How did you save the local json file in the first place?

Comment: You can use UserDefaults to store current version of the app. If you really want to use json. First read the json in to NSMutableDictionary. Then change your value. And save dictionary to disk as a json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a .plist file as it can easily store a NSDictionary or NSArray (which can be translated from a JSON object)

try the code below:

```
//store plist file in documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"localJSON.plist"];
if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
//its an array
NSArray * dataToStore =  jsonObject;
[dataToStore writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
} 
else
{
//its a dictionary
NSDictionary * dataToStore =  jsonObject;
[dataToStore writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```